# Is this a wet moon?

Tags: moon-phases

Tonight around 12:20 AM I realized that the top part (instead of the side) of the moon was missing. I live at a country in the tropics.

I took this picture with my phone so it isn't very good.

[image]

After googling I found out about the wet moon phase in Wikipedia and I wonder if that is what I was looking at.

[Wet Moon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRx6w.jpg)

Comment: It's not exactly a wet moon,since it is not a crescent moon. It's Gibbous Moon

Comment: And the reason for the top not showing is the same as in a wet moon?

Comment: What do you mean by reason?. It's one of the moon phase,like wet moon which is also a moon phase but with a fancy name.[wet moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wet_moon)

Comment: Sorry I meant to ask if this was just a phase "similar" to the wet moon or something else. I did ask cause I have never seen it before and wasn't sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not a wet moon, as wet moon occurs when the horn of the crescent moon pointed at an angle away from the horizon. In your picture, that is not a crescent Moon. It is may be in the first quarter or last quarter, so Gibbous moon is more suitable.

See [Moon phases.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_phase)